# Adjectival prepositional phrase as a noun modifier

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Does an adjectival prepositional phrase ***always immediately*** follow a noun phrase that it modifies? If not, could you please give an example where the above is not true? Actually I can't think of one right now. Thank you.

Here are a few examples that show prepositional phrases immediately following noun phrases.

The cat **on the shed** is black.

Here 'on the shed' is an adjectival prepositional phrase modifying 'the cat'. It immediately follows the noun phrase.

Few more examples:

I would like to buy some flowers **in a glass vase.**

People **from many different countries** have visited this place.

Comment: Multi-hyphenated PPs may occasionally occur in the attributive position (**off-the-wall** adjective:
 highly unusual : BIZARRE
_an off-the-wall sense of humor_ [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-the-wall)]), but by this time they're single lexemes, compound adjectives, if they're really acceptable.

Comment: Few rules of grammar are ***always*** true. It is always clearer to put a prepositional phrase (it's not necessary to call them "adjectival" -- that just means they're modifying a noun; it's not a property of the phrase itself) right after the noun it modifies. There are rules that change that configuration, but they have a cost and are not common.

Comment: What about: 'the lions were angry over at the city zoo'?